# No difference in run-time for CPU &GPU & TPU usage in Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I perform some preprocessing issues which takes approx. 14 min for CPU runtime in Google Colab. But when I switch to GPU or TPU the runtime period doesn't change, though it shows:

> Found TPU at: grpc://10.113.22.130:8470

Is there any specific way to utilize the resource of TPU to reduce the runtime period?

Comment: Have you made any code changes to utilize the GPU or TPU?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually utilize the GPU/TPU in Colab then you generally do need to add additional code (the runtime doesn't automatically detect the hardware, at least for TPU).

[Here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/tpu.ipynb) is a Colab example you can follow to utilize the TPU. However I will note that generally data preprocessing runs on the CPU anyways regardless if running on CPU or GPU and the magic of the accelerator kicks in when you accelerate actual training.

If you want to speed up your preprocessing, the best practice is to use `tf.data`. You can learn more about how TF data is used to improve performance [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance).